Rise time and fall of MOSFET - Testing setup
According to this datasheet the MOSFET is able to switch at the following speed:

The MOSFET are used on a buck converter. Suppose I need to switch 0-5 A and suppose I have an inductance equal to 5 nH describing the sum of the inductances (traces + ESL), it means that I will have a voltage spike equal to around 9 V. It appears to me to be a lot and it is far from what I find on a previous board with the same MOSFET. Moreover, the resistor on the gate of the MOSFET was equal to 0 Ω. So the MOSFET was probably even faster than the time indicated into the datasheet (Rgate = 1.6 Ω).
So I think the testing setup is making the switching times faster than with my board but I do not know why it would be the case. If anayone is able to help me to understand why my board (buck converter) will slows down the switching times or why the testing setup is faster than my board?
Here is the test circuit for measuring rise and fall time:

As it can be seen there is no inductive load and I have the intuition that it could change the rise time and fall time. But I do not know how to explain it. If someone is able to explain my intuition it would be great :)
Thank you and have a nice day!
-------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------
For clarifying my post, I add an edit of my previous post.
The buck converter is not working in DCM and it is working in CCM. So it is possible to see the current jumping from 0A to 5A in few ns. The slope of the current is not limited by the main inductor of the buck but by the inductor of the traces and the speed of the MOSFETs/diodes. In any case even in DCM it is possible to see the current jumping from 5A to 0A in few ns.
Have a nice day.

What input voltage is the buck converter using? If that voltage is already below your calucated 9V peak voltage, then it will just take longer for the 5A to flow. That the FET reaches full conductivity in 4ns does not automatically mean that the current reaches 5A this fast.

The test circuit shown has no way of discharging the gate other than via the oscilloscope input. Remember that the gate is basically a capacitor.

The gate must always have a certain potential; it must never be floating.

Jess, what you must not do is amend a question that has received an answer without some form of clear notification in the question that you have added new words else, people scanning my answer could say that it doesn't address your question. Of course, with clear edits that makes it less problematic. However, there is a more problematic thing and that is you saying the current is between 0 amps and 5 amps then saying you are operating in CCM so, I'm going to roll back your question to how it was when I made my answer so you can have a think about what you need to do.

"Jess, what you must not do is amend a question that has received an answer without some form of clear notification in the question that you have added new words else" @Andyaka is wrong. The bottom of the post contains a link to the edit history for anyone interested. I don't see a need for the rollback, except that edit did not cite the source of the added image -- is it yours, Jess, or did you get it from somewhere else (and, if so, where)? We need to know either way.

@Null I don't think moderators are being consistent about this. I've seen Sam Gibson roll-back at least one question that suffered from edit-creep. Apart from anything else, the edit Jess made didn't supposedly fix the problem of not knowing what the valley current is.

@Andyaka I roll back questions that invalidate answers, too. A single edit to add an image and two short sentences does not invalidate your answer nor does it constitute "edit-creep". The only problem with the edit is that the image does not have a cited source.

The test circuit is presumably made with minimal stray inductance, and a resistive load as indicated.
Also in common use is an inductive load, with a catch diode specified (usually another identical transistor, in a double-pulse test, and body diode recovery is measured at the same time).
Note that, at such short time scales, it may be impossible to avoid inductive effects, and so there will be some impact upon measured values -- without the actual fixture and layout provided in the datasheet, we can only guess.
Switching time is dominated by impedance and capacitance.  Notice the low drive resistance of 1.6Ω.  The high drain current of 50A also charges Coss rapidly on turn-off; at lower currents (higher RL), this time constant may dominate, raising td(off) and tf independent of RG.  These are easily enough demonstrated in a circuit simulator such as LTSpice.
You are comparing datasheet parameters to an instance of some circuit, but you don't mention what that circuit is, or any component values or the layout, so we are unable to provide further insight in that respect.

Thank you for your answer. I will try to test several mosfet on my board and try to measure the speed of commutation to better understand what really happens ! Thank you for your help :)


The MOSFET are used on a buck converter.

and

If anyone is able to help me to understand why my board (buck
converter) will slows down the switching times or why the testing
setup is faster than my board?

I'll mention this first: if you are designing a buck converter, the rate of change of current is determined not by the trace inductance (very small naturally) but by the value of the inductor used for energy storage and transfer (in the micro henry range usually).

Suppose I need to switch 0 to 5A and suppose I have an inductance
equal to 5nH describing the sum of the inductances (traces + ESL) , it means that I will have a voltage spike equal to around 9V.

It's not relevant in the case of a buck converter because di/dt will be dictated by the main inductor and not trace inductance. As an example, if the input supply is 10 volts, the desired output voltage is 5 volts and, the inductance is 5 μH then di/dt will be 1 amp per microsecond i.e. much slower than what the MOSFET can achieve when pushed to its limit.
If you then used that di/dt with the inductance of the trace (5 nH) you get a volt drop of: -
$$10^6\times 5\times 10^{-9} = \text{5 mV}$$

"rate of change of current is determined not by the trace inductance (very small naturally) but by the value of the inductor" -- which rate, where, and when? As the only context provided by the question is a lone MOSFET switching a given current, this statement seems inconsistent; perhaps a schematic and waveforms would clarify.

@TimWilliams the question clearly states that he is designing a buck converter.

Switching times are also clearly in focus; are you saying the dI/dt during switching is determined by L?

@TimWilliams I'm surprised you needed to ask: $\dfrac{V}{L} = \dfrac{di}{dt}$

In CCM, in the instant the switch goes from off to on, commutating from 0 to I_out - Iripple(pk) in some ns?

I suppose in CCM the valley current might be an amp or so if the peak current is maybe 5 amps so yes, you have a point @TimWilliams but, the OP does say he has to switch "0 to 5A" (now modified by winny to state 0-5 A).

I will clarify my post

@Jess what you must not do is amend a question that has received an answer without some form of clear notification in the question that you have added new words else, people scanning my answer could say that it doesn't address your question. Of course, with clear edits that makes it less problematic. However, there is a more problematic thing and that is you saying the current is between 0 amps and 5 amps then saying you are operating in CCM so, I'm going to roll back your question to how it was when I made my answer so you can have a think about what you need to do.
